Why isn't my new shower valve sending water to the shower head?
I installed a Glacier Bay Oswell shower valve and no water is coming out of the shower head.

The shower valve is installed in the correct position.
The bottom was capped as there’s no tub
Removed the cartridge, plugged it and turned the water on, it worked.
Buy new cartridge, same issue.
I’ve even blew air in both directions before changing the cartridge thinking there could have been a clog, but nothing.
The screw valves are open on the shower valve.
When I loosen the chrome that holds the cartridge, water flows perfectly. However, you cannot turn it off with the handle since it’s been loosened.

Does anyone have any ideas why this would keep happening?




The image isn't mirrored. (The C is correct.) You're simply showing us the rear of the valve body.

Did air blow through the valve ok?

This is admittedly a bit of a shot in the dark, but it looks as if the hot water is turned on and the cold is not. (This based on the position of the shutoff screws)
If the hot is on and the cold is not, the cartridge would close flow so all hot water is not passed to the shower head and a possible scald occurs. It is doing it's job.  This also explains why another cartridge does the same thing and why having no cartridge allows water to flow.
